# how to disable first item of a list from being sortable and drop target

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a list of items and I want to make the first item in the list unsortable and unmovable. The first item in the list should always stay as the first item in the list. However, I can't seem to get it to work.here's my sorting code:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#lineup').sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    items: ".ui-state-enabled"
    cancel: ".ui-state-disabled"
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
  );
```

and i'm using content_tag_for to load it up:

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs.nav-stacked#lineup{"data-update-url" => sort_lineups_url}
  - @pieces.each_with_index do |piece, index|
    - if index == 0
      = content_tag_for(:li, piece, :class => 'ui-state-disabled') do
        = link_to "#{(index + 1).to_s + ' - ' + piece.name}", '#'
    - else
      = content_tag_for(:li, piece, :class => 'ui-state-enabled') do
        = link_to "#{(index + 1).to_s + ' - ' + piece.name}", '#'
```

what am i doing wrong? nothing i do seems to prevent the first item from being sorted and/or moved

Comment: Easiest approach is probably to have two adjacent lists styled to appear as one. With a little thought you could develop a function/plugin to automate things - split out the first LI; insert it into a new UL; insert the new UL before the original; add/remove classes as necessary.

Comment: is that the easiest? seems difficult since jquery ui has an example of exactly what i'm looking to do (disable sort, disable drop) but i can't seem to get it to work. I think there should be a way to fix what i have

Comment: "should" being the operative word!

Comment: fair enough, but isn't it already done on the jquery ui example site? why would my implementation potentially not be able to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the UI example please.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#items    it's the top example, where you specify which items can be sorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mmm, hard to say for certain. I've not used sortable/draggable combination before, moreover the UI documentation doesn't expressly address the sortable/draggable combination.

However, from what I have read in the documentation, something like this should work :

```
$(function() {
    $("#lineup li").disableSelection().addClass('ui-state-default').eq(0).addClass('ui-state-disabled');//alternatively, write classes as HTML attributes
    $("#lineup").sortable({
        items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)" //should disable draggable and sortable
    });
});
```

Comment: I've been looking for this answer.  This part `$("#lineup li").disableSelection().addClass('ui-state-default').eq(0).addClass('ui-state-disabled');` really helped.  Thanks.