# AngularJS - ui-sortable - How to disable sorting on just one item from the sortable list?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui

Here is a [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9W9XilAO7LS6aAhR0iXk?p=preview).  [updated the plunk based on below answers]

[Updated Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KkTEakiWiiTjqSSndq9j?p=preview)

How can I disable sorting on just one or two items. For example, item 1 and item 3, so the user can't move those two items ?

I tried

```
   $scope.sortableOptions = {
       disabled:true,
   };
```

in sortableOptions, but that disables sorting on the whole list.

I'm looking for something like

```
  <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list">    
  <div ng-repeat="item in list">    
    <div ng-switch on="item.text">    

      <div ng-switch-when="Item 1" >    
        <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions.disabled=true">{{item.text}} - Sorting disabled</div>    
      </div>  

     <div ng-switch-default>    
        <div>{{item.text}} - Sorting enabled</div>    
      </div>  

    </div>    
  </div>    
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can configure a class for items that should not be dragged:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
cancel: ".unsortable",
```

Then conditionally add that class in `ngRepeat`:

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list" class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="item in list" class="item"  
      ng-class="{'unsortable': item.text == 'Item 2'}">
    {{item.text}}
```

**Update**
You can prevent the item from being sorted like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319663/how-to-disable-first-item-of-a-list-from-being-sortable-and-drop-target?rq=1):

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
cancel: ".unsortable",
items: "li:not(.unsortable)",
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for most of the parts. But when I drag item3 and place it on top of item 2, item2 gets dropped from its original position. In my case, I only want the item1 to be fixed in a way that when the user tries to place any other items on top of item 1, sortableOptions should either trigger a sortable.cancel() or just drop the item below item 1. Here is my updated plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/9W9XilAO7LS6aAhR0iXk?p=preview

Comment: Didn't get your updated answer before I posted mine...but the behavior you're getting is quite similar to what's happening on my example. For the most part it works...but if you drag Item 3...or Item 4 on top of Item 1, Item 1 is sorted down :S

Comment: items: "li:not(.unsortable)" prevents the unsortable items from being moved.

Comment: because you're using DIV's instead of Li's, use items: "div:not(.unsortable)" :)

Here's a Plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/9W9XilAO7LS6aAhR0iXk?p=preview

Comment: i see, Antonio.  My code sample is for the plunker linked to in the question, but you are right that the code block in the question uses divs.  if jundev is unclear how to implement the solution, i will clarify the answer with an edit.

Comment: I've implemented 'div:not(.unsortable)', and it works well, except when I drag item 3 and drop it just above item 2, item 1 gets pushed down, and item 3 goes to the top. I will try to figure out a way around this, but any help would be much appreciated. Thanks. Here is my new plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/KkTEakiWiiTjqSSndq9j?p=preview

Comment: At the moment, as I only need the first item to be unsortable, i've put it in a separate ng-repeat with a case condition, and have made sure it doesn't appear again in the second ng-repeat that contains the sortable items. It seems to do the job for now. http://plnkr.co/edit/9dV46mVD2c4Y9t7i4PqP?p=preview

Comment: I used cancel, but this is blocking click on textfield's, do you have a solution for it?

Comment: Ok I solved it by following this, http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/jquery-textbox-in-sortable-is-not-clickable-selectable , thanks to this blog

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to implement the update option?

From the ui-sortable documentation, a modified and over simplified version for your use case:

First, add a enabled property to your array:

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        tmpList.push({
          text: 'Item ' + i,
          value: i,
          enabled: true
        });
      }
```

and then assert it's status in the sortableOptions:

```
    $scope.sortableOptions = {
      update: function(e, ui) {
        if (ui.item.scope().item.enabled === false) {
          ui.item.sortable.cancel();
   }}};
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried that too. But, it gets called only after the item is dragged. So, it still allows me to move the item from its original position. Here is the updated plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/9W9XilAO7LS6aAhR0iXk?p=preview

Comment: Ah! I see. Yes, it doesn't allow you to drag it...but it can be sorted :|