# jQuery sortable - only move one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[I'm using jQuery's sortable UI feature.](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)

I've got an unordered list with a few list items. When you click one of the list items it becomes the "active" list item. I'd like to make this (and only this) list item moveable, to any spot in the ul.

```
<ul>
  <li class="li_item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="li_item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="li_item_active">Item 3</li>
  <li class="li_item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="li_item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="li_item">Item 6</li>      
</ul>
```

Just to be clear, any item on this list can become active. But I only want the active element to be moveable.

Comment: Only active item, not others? Do you have any code to start with?

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour? You can't move multiple objects on the same time or do you have 2 mice? o.o

Comment: @JimmyKnoot Well, it will only switch to the active element when you click (and keyup your click). The sortable works with holding down your mouse so it doesn't switch to the active class.

Comment: @TrevorW I'm not quite sure I understand what you exactly want to do..

Comment: I think this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319663/how-to-disable-first-item-of-a-list-from-being-sortable-and-drop-target. it's not your exact solution, but you can use the method to deactivate the necessary li's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`cancel`](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items) option. Like this:

```
var $ul = $("#sortable"),
    $li = $ul.children();

$ul.sortable({
    cancel: ".item-disabled"
});

$ul.on('click', '.item', function() {
    $li.removeClass('item-active').addClass('item-disabled');
    $(this).toggleClass('item-active item-disabled');
})

$li.addClass('item-disabled');
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Eqc7v/1/

Comment: +1, very simple and easy to understand code. Exactly what I was looking for.